# C Programming: Error in program. Won't show Max/Min/Average of files inputted by user

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I'm attempting to create a code that the user inputs a filename and the program will then find the Min, Max, and Average of the numbers in the file.

This is a sample of a file the user would input into the program (the # are comments and would be ignored):

```
#Data from field experiment 312A
#2015-01-12
35.6
3.75
#2015-01-13
9
#2015-01-14
43.43
7.0001
```

And this is what I have for my code for the moment, I tried combining different methods, but fear I am just too lost at this point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  char ch, file_name[25];
  FILE *fp;
  double average, num = 0, min = 0, max = 0, sum = 0, N;
  int i;

  printf("Please enter the name of the file to load:\n");
  scanf(file_name);

  fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

  if (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &N) == 1)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      if (num < min || i == 0)
        min = num;
      if (num > max || i == 0)
        max = num;
      sum += num;
    }

  fclose(fp);
  average = sum/N;

  printf("Smallest: %7.2lf\n", min);
  printf("Largest: %7.2lf\n", max);
  printf("Average: %7.2lf\n", average);
  return(0);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should pose a clear question; what is not working, what output are you getting, what do you expect. Make the code minimal and working...

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Should give you all the answers you need quickly.

Comment: The code complies, when it runs I can input a file name but then I receive a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code,

```
  scanf(file_name);
```

is **wrong usage** of `scanf()`, you're missing a format specifier. You have to change that to

```
  scanf("%24s", file_name);    //%s  is the format specifier for a string input
```

Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) for more details.

Apart from that, there are logical errors in your program. You're reading the file only once, which is not what you want. Also, there is no meaning of the `for()` loop.

My advice will be:

1. Open the file, then **check for success of `foepn()`.** Otherwise, don't procceed.
2. Read a whole line using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).
3. Convert the input string to `float` using [`strtod()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod).
4. If conversion success, check for `< min` and `> max`, change accordingly, and sum the result.
5. Otherwise, if conversion fails, it is a comment, ignore that line.
6. Continue untill `fgets()` returns NULL (erach end of the file)
7. Calculate the average based on `sum / (number of successful conversions)`
8. Print the `sum`, `max` and `min`.
9. Close the file.

That said, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

---

EDIT:

A pseudo-code (as requested for better understanding)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>


int main(void)
{
char file_name[25] = {0};
FILE *fp = NULL;;
double average = 0, min = DBL_MAX, max = 0, sum = 0;
int N = 0;
char buf[128] = {0}; // buffer tyo be used with fgets()

ask for the filename  (using `scanf("%24s", file_name);`)

open the file (using `fp = fopen(file_name, "r");`)

    if file cannot be opened successfully (`if (!fp)`)
          exit

while (reading a complete line from file using `fgets(buf, 128, fp)` != EOF)  //EOF ==> end of file
{
    if (buf[0] ==  `#`)  //comment, no propcessing reqd, continue
        continue;

    val = strtod(buf, NULL);  //you should use proper error checking, as metioned in the man page

    if (val)  // valid float value found
    {
        if ( val < min )
            min = val;
        else if ( val > max )
            max = val;

        sum += val;   //add the value
        N++;          //increase the counter
    }
}

close the file (using `fclose(fp);`)
calculate `average = sum/N;`

  printf("Smallest: %7.2f\n", min);
  printf("Largest: %7.2f\n", max);
  printf("Average: %7.2f\n", average);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: and ignore the comment lines starting with #

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon I think it will cause failure to `strtod()`, isn't it?

Comment: yeah,It is just my style to avoid running into errors when i know something in advance.

Comment: @SouravGhosh With your advice, I am unclear in how to implement it. Any clarification would be great.

Comment: @iamriotus take it step by step, don't try to ggrab all at a time. which step (in 1-9) you're facing issues? You can start by reading the linked manual pages.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Firstly, I assumed that fgets() was to replace scanf() but that just causes more errors to pop up, probably due to the fact that fscanf() was still in the code. Also, converting the input sting to float? Which input string is that? From what I gathered from the manual, it isn't the FILE one is it? Thanks for taking the time to clear things up.

Comment: @iamriotus ok, i'll add a pseudocode. Give me some time

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thank you, sorry if I'm being difficult. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @iamriotus see the updated answer. Hope you can get the idea from that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `min` with a very large number.

Your `if` needs `{}` otherwise the code executes other than you think.

before you calculate `sum/N` you should check `N>0`.

Your combination of `fscanf` and `for` does not work this way.